Jakarta PrimeFaces 'p:commandButton' won't execute my 'action(Listener)'
Jakarta JavaFaces 'h:commandButton' (OK):
<h:form id="form">
    <h:commandButton value="h:doButtonActionListener" process="@this" actionListener="#{beWhereWhenController.doButtonActionListener()}"/>
    ...
</>

Controller:
@Named("beWhereWhenController")
@RequestScoped
public class BeWhereWhenController {
    ...
    public void doButtonActionListener() {
        System.out.println(">>>>> doButtonActionListener .....");
    }
}

Displays:
INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) >>>>> doButtonActionListener .....
...

But using 'PrimeFaces' 'p:commandButton':
<p:commandButton value="p:doButtonActionListener" process="@this" actionListener="#{beWhereWhenController.doButtonActionListener()}"/>

Displays nothing!
Using:
PrimeFaces Jakarta 14.0.6

WildFly Distribution - 34.0.0.Final
Jakarta EE 11.0.0-M4
Jakarta Faces 4.1.1
Mojarra 4.1.0
JDK 23.0.1
macOS Sequoia 15.1 (UNIX)

Have looked at:
Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes
Didn't show anything obvious.
h:commandButton works on Mojarra but p:commandButton doesn't.
TIA
(2) Found the solution:
Fixed with adding: ajax="false"
<p:commandButton value="p:doButtonActionListener actionListener" actionListener="#{beWhereWhenController.doButtonActionListener()}" ajax="false" process="@this" />


So if the "Moderators and anyone with 3000 reputation may vote to close a question as a duplicate." & knew the solution why hadn't they answered it? They knew it was due to  'ajax="false"'.
